# Is it possible to handle swipe gestures in PWA application?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, swipe, gesture

I'm creating a PWA, ASP server side and JS client side.
Users interact nicely with it using buttons.
The boss ask me if we can implement something like "scroll between app screen" or "perform some operation (edit, delete..) on elements" using the swipe gesture, as many native apps do.
Is there an easy way? or any way anyhow?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Made an example that logs out the direction of a swipe here: https://jsfiddle.net/jamiesmith/e9gndqpc/3/

Below is the code pulled from the linked example that console logs out the direction of a swipe (up, down, left or right). You can search it for `left swipe` or `up swipe` etc to find where you would call some function / do something per direction.

It also checks a function called `ignoreSwipe` so we can add a class named `noswipe` to elements we specifically want to ignore gestures from. It's included because I found, especially with a PWA, you might listen for swipes on a drawer component to close it but may want to ignore swipes from a child element, like a menu item, etc.

```
let _xDown, _yDown;

document.querySelector('div.app')
    .addEventListener(
        'touchstart',
        handleTouchStart,
        false
    );
document.querySelector('div.app')
    .addEventListener(
        'touchmove',
        handleTouchMove,
        false
    );


function ignoreSwipe(event) {
    // if some touches come from elements with ignoreswipe class > ignore
    return Array.from(event.touches).some((t) =>
        t.target.classList.contains('noswipe')
    );
}

function handleTouchStart(event) {
    if (ignoreSwipe(event)) {
        _xDown = undefined;
        _yDown = undefined;
        return;
    }

    const firstTouch = event.touches[0];
    _xDown = firstTouch.clientX;
    _yDown = firstTouch.clientY;
}

function handleTouchMove(event) {

    if (!_xDown || !_yDown) {
        return;
    }

    const xUp = event.touches[0].clientX;
    const yUp = event.touches[0].clientY;

    const xDiff = _xDown - xUp;
    const yDiff = _yDown - yUp;

    if (Math.abs(xDiff) > Math.abs(yDiff)) {
        /*most significant*/
        if (xDiff > 0) {
            /* left swipe */
            console.log('app: left swipe ', true);
        } else {
            /* right swipe */
            console.log('app: right swipe ', true);
        }
    } else {
        if (yDiff > 0) {
            /* up swipe */
            console.log('app: up swipe ', true);
        } else {
            /* down swipe */
            console.log('app: down swipe ', true);
        }
    }

    /* reset values */
    _xDown = null;
    _yDown = null;
}
```

Some docs the example makes use of:

TouchEvent.touches - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent/touches

TouchEvent.touchstart & touchmove - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Comment: is this left and right swiping or up and down swiping?

Comment: @chovy all four. Search code example for `left swipe` or `up swipe` etc to find where you would call some function / do something per direction. In the example it console logs the direction.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of libraries that can help implement touch gestures for PWAs - have a look at Hammerjs:

https://hammerjs.github.io/

Your question is fairly generic though, there might be better solutions but that's just one off the top of my head

Comment: Thanks Thomas. It's a good starting point.
I was hoping in something more... "straight" than >1K code rows, but I can put my head on it.
My question is fairly generic because my need are fairly generic right now :)